# Please show all migrated-in posts in /review

Tags: feature-request, review, migrated-questions

Migrated posts often require special attention. They usually at least require some retagging, and are often lower quality.

There is a [tab in the 10k tools showing imported posts](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/posts/migrated/here), with imported posts. This list should be in `/review`, visible to all users who can view `/review` at all, and with all the inline review goodness.