# Ability to review questions being transferred from SO before they appear

Tags: feature-request, migration, moderation, migrated-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please just close garbage questions, instead of moving them to Programmers SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89169/please-just-close-garbage-questions-instead-of-moving-them-to-programmers-se)
>   [Show mods all network posts with pending migration votes to their site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94536/show-mods-all-network-posts-with-pending-migration-votes-to-their-site)

A significant proportion of questions being transferred to PSE from SO are being closed pretty rapidly upon arrival.

An example of a question which was transferred today which (to my mind) should obviously have just been closed is https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/88846/what-are-you-doing-with-cables-under-workrtable but this isn't an isolated case.

As a first step would it be possible for someone to write a script to see the percentage of questions that get closed after being migrated - possibly breaking it down between those migrated unanimously and those where there were also votes to close for other reasons?

If that shows that a significant proportion do just get closed, instead of them just appearing, would it be possible to have them transfer to a holding area where they can be reviewed (by mods or suitably rep-ed up users - appearing in the tools area) prior to appearing on the site? I'd suggest a threshold of two (or more) users have to accept the question.

If it's accepted then it appears as normal, if not then it gets returned to SO closed with a comment explaining what's happened.

Sometimes it just feels like SO is the neighbour who keeps their garden tidy by throwing all their rubbish into yours...

Note: Copy of [Ability to review questions being transferred from SO before they appear](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1211/ability-to-review-questions-being-transferred-from-so-before-they-appear) on meta.PSE

**EDIT**: In terms of it's an isolated example:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/87988/asked-for-suggestions-on-a-topic-of-a-silverlight-project

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/88361/6-months-industrial-training-net-net-or-android

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/87526/how-to-improve-programming-skills

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/87233/using-a-trademark-name-in-your-software-application

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/88186/table-of-programming-languages-by-grammar

I've stopped at five (plus the original one), all from the past *five days*, all closed and I've excluded those closed because they're duplicates and one or two that were closed that I personally think are fine.

I get that people don't necessarily know the ins and outs of Programmers but if that's the case then surely they shouldn't be migrating stuff there.

Comment: A migration limbo... nice.

Comment: @Daniel - It's not isolated, I'll go find more if you want. But more to the point, since then Programmers has had a bit of a crack down on crap and this really doesn't help us.

Comment: @Daniel: This is not a dupe, because the Q in your link only says don't migrate crap. Jon actually has a suggestion to deal with it and a feature request to let them throw the crap back at SO.

Comment: @Jon I think it's in your best interest to prove that it's not just an isolated incident to strengthen your case.  Right now your feature request is more [discussion] and really more of a complaint than an outline of a feature you would like added.

Comment: @Daniel - Another five from the last five days added (excludes things closed for being dupes) - all just low quality questions. How many more do you want? I agree that this may not be a good solution but I do think there is an issue.

Comment: @Jon cool, I think that helps a lot.  I'm very hesitant to migrate to Programmers.SE (mainly because of the question I linked), it appears that others aren't, and this might be one approach to fixing it.

Comment: Please see rough stats on: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93440/recourse-for-bad-migrated-questions before proposing complicated solutions.

Comment: @Shog9 - Thanks for that, the data was actually what I was asking for in the first instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a Programmers moderator... I don't think things are that bad, though I don't have the numbers on hand to support that.

The "migration limbo" idea has been pitched before and denied every time, for good reasons. We don't want questions to be unanswerable for a period of time. For every bad migration there are several good migrations and we do not want to prevent askers from getting views and responses. That goes against the very nature of Stack Exchange.

So I think a better use of our collective time would to try and figure out how to prevent bad migrations from happening in the first place.

Migrations are initiated either by 3k+ users or moderators. In the latter case, moderators generally talk to other moderators and we often get a heads up on a migration or we get to "approve" it in chat before it happens.

For 3k+ users, this is more complicated. It's not reasonable to expect every 3k+ user on Stack Overflow to know the details of Programmers. But I do think that correcting some of the references to and descriptions of Programmers in the vote to close dialog and the Stack Overflow FAQ would be helpful.

We have a discussion of this going on on [Programmers Meta](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1838/proposal-for-inserting-a-so-xor-pe-sentence-in-the-faq). I favour changing the Programmers tagline from "Q&A for expert programmers interested in professional discussions on software development" to something more along the lines of "Q&A for expert programmers interested in conceptual software development problems".

Another idea I'm personally fond of is to [show mods all network posts with pending migration votes to their site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94536/show-mods-all-network-posts-with-pending-migration-votes-to-their-site). This way we'd have the ability to stop *some* of the bad migrations without landing questions in a limbo they may never get out of.

Comment: If there are five votes to close but only three of them vote for migration, does it get migrated?

Comment: @Jon Majority wins right now, so yes. [This post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89242/require-more-than-simple-majority-of-close-votes-to-migrate) proposes changing that behaviour. (Man, I'm on a roll with meta references today. :))

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm off to up vote that, I suspect it would make a bit of a difference and is probably a better solution than limbo.

Comment: @Anna Will (Won't)'s comment on that linked question seems to indicate that it's 4/5 required and not just 3/5 .. not sure which is correct

Comment: @Daniel I thought that was his suggestion for how the existing mechanics could be changed.