# Reverse the migration workflow

Tags: feature-request, migration, moderator-tools

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create an Accept Migration voting mechanism for migrated questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109216/create-an-accept-migration-voting-mechanism-for-migrated-questions)

Currently, for a migration between SE sites to happpen either 5 users (if a migration path is enabled) or one moderator from the *source* site have to decide to migrate to a specific target site.

This workflow is problematic as those users deciding are not necessarily very familiar with the target site and the specific rules of that site.

Moderators often ask the target site mods whether they want the question before migrating, but doing that in chat is certainly not optimal. One of the target site mods needs to respond, and the source site mod then needs to be available at that point to migrate. It's just more complicated than needed.

But the main problem in my opinion is that the wrong users get to decide whether to migrate or not. The source site users are certainly qualified to decide whether a question is off-topic for their site, but they are just not the ideal users to ask whether the question is on-topic on some other site. The users that should decide that are the users of the target migration site.

I propose the following migration workflow:

- Users or moderators close as off-topic, but should be migrated and select the target site
- When the question is closed, a flag is raised on the target site about the possible migration
- The flag can be agreed on or declined by 10k users and mods
- If the flag is accepted, the migration is automatically performed, whithout any further intervention needed from the source site mods

The advantage would be for mods that they would only need to act once now, they wouldn't have to ask the target site mods and wait for their response. It should also lead to a lower rate of bad migrations as now the target site users decide about that.

There are some details that would need further thought, e.g. should normal users get the same free-form migration textfield as mods. Should the pending migration be shown on the question, as it might be a friendlier message than an outright closing as off-topic? Should moderators get the option to migrate without target site approval?

Comment: Why are they asking other mods only for migrations in the first place? Why was this ever a need? Don't the sites have their own public rooms?

Comment: @random Because mods complained when other mods migrated crap? It's probably not needed in many cases, but done anyway. And if you don't have any experience with the target site you have a high chance of getting it wrong. For example, the Skeptics scope is probably not well-understood by a large majority of the mods, it just not very obvious. And the public chat of many sites is pretty much deserted, so no help there.