# Prevent multiple migrations by moderators

Tags: feature-request, migration, vote-to-close, moderator-tools

Since multiple migrations are a Bad Thing for the poor question-asker (and apparently may violate some key concepts of quantum mechanics and cause Al Gore to become angry), and seeing as how we now have a cool rejected migration system that tracks and handles these things, the ability to double-migrate questions should really be disabled by technical means rather than just an administrative prohibition.

This could be accomplished in several ways - the most logical seems to be having the "Off-Topic" close reason for questions that were migrated default to plain-vanilla-off-topic and not bother showing the migration list.

Comment: It already does this for regular users. It's moderators that are the problem here.

Comment: @ChrisF We should never be trusted with special powers

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by multiple migrations? Just migrating a question from site A to site B, which migrates it to site C?

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ yeah - basically if SO migrates something to SF and SF's mods then kick it to SU the world ends...

Comment: I reckon that a question that's been bounced around this much probably won't be a good question, but what if there are legitimate reasons to do so? Say something gets migrated to SO from SU, but after further review and comments, it really belongs on SF. Do you just want to block the possibility of migrating it again?

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ the preferred path is for the intermediate site to reject the migration, and the original site to send it to its proper end destination.  (In practice these ARE usually crap questions and *SHOULD* have been killed at their origin site, but occasionally a bad user migration escapes before mods can step in and send it to a good home...)

Comment: please pay heed to @ChrisF -- this is *only possible if the moderator is the one making the mistake*.

Comment: @voretaq7 "preventive" feature that would likely make it less of an issue is [suggested migrations review at target site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/151345/165773 "proposed here"): in your [example scenario](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151589/prevent-multiple-migrations-by-moderators#comment434886_151589 "'SO migrates something to SF and SF's mods then kick it to SU'"), SF users would have a chance to block migration before it happens

Answer (score 4):

I'd buy into this. If the 'Close - Off topic - Belongs on' simply added a flag to the flag queue after the question was closed asking a moderator to migrate it, that would work.

To the user, the question would be closed as off-topic; but at least behind the scenes we'd see where the community thought it should go and make a decision based on that.

Comment: That could work too - maybe somehow tack a comment on the originating site's question telling them why the migration was rejected (and what site the receiving site thought should get it).  Not sure how much extra complexity that adds for implementation though...