# Hide migration dialog by default

Tags: feature-request, migration

I am learning about the issues surrounding topic migration.  I now understand that a lot of migration requests are rejected, and the target site moderators are sometimes overwhelmed by the incoming deluge of migrated questions from SO in particular.

I originally had "remove migration dialog" in the title, but that was just sensationalist. I still think there ought to be a mechanism for migrating questions.  But given that so many migration requests are unwelcome, perhaps it should be made harder, or less obvious.

When I first learned to click the *Close*  button to vote to have an off-topic or otherwise inappropriate question removed, I was somewhat surprised to be presented with the migration dropdown when I clicked "off-topic".  I am now suggesting that this mechanism **invites <del>new users</del> *users who do not read meta* to suggest migration** when in fact that option should be reserved only for "interesting" questions.

So the slightly less tongue-in-cheek suggestion would be to make the drop-down simpler.

> This question is
>
> ◉ off-topic
>
> - Questions on Stack Overflow are expected to relate to programming or software development within the scope defined in the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq). Consider editing the question or leaving comments for improvement if you believe the question can be reworded to fit within the scope. Read more about [closed questions](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#close) here.
>
> ◯ on-topic for a different site in the StackExchange network ... >

... and then the "on-topic" second-layer dropdown could contain the migration list, or some new replacement for it.  Hiding it behind a second layer might be a first step towards making it more usable -- I'm thinking perhaps each user could have a customized list of sites they actually participate in, and only be able to migrate to those; but that's a topic for a separate posting.

Comment: Your base assumption "invites new users to suggest migration" is wrong. New users can't vote to migrate a question, it requires 3000 points which usually takes time and experience to gain. Moreover, users should choose a site **only if they are sure** not out of a whim.

Comment: Make that "users who have the prerequisite privileges, but who do not read meta" rather than "new users".  Personally, I achieved 3k in something like 3 months, which qualifies as "relatively new" in my book.  The point of my suggestion is to try to enforce "only if they are sure", or at least discourage "on a whim", which I think the current system doesn't accomplish.

Comment: related: [suggested migrations review at target site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/151345/165773) "queue... at target site... would contain a list of questions flagged / voted for migration. Target site users with appropriate privileges (eg close voters, or editors etc...) could submit their feedback on whether the proposed question is a good fit for migration..."

Answer (score 1):

If our answer to a problem is to slow the process down then we don't have the right solution.  If there is a problem with migration, then we need to find a better way to fix it than making a user click more.

**Clicks are the devil!**

Comment: While my proposed design would require two clicks where today you only need one, it is not a crucial detail. In fact it might make more sense to offer "it is off-topic" and "it is on-topic for ..." as two alternatives in the top-level dialog. Thanks for your comment!